# How to have multi BindingContext in a page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How to create a 2 pass view? didnt found anything similar on google

I have a onePage.xaml.cs, which is calling OneViewModel. Inside oneViewModel, it will refresh page and it should call twoViewModel. finally twoViewModel will call some random view

how can i edit view.xaml.cs file to handle 2 different ViewsModels? 1st pass should bind to oneViewModel and 2nd pass should bind to twoViewModel

onePage.xaml (View)

```
<Label Text={Binding TestLabel} />
```

onePage.xaml.cs (View)

```
    public onePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           BindingContext = new oneViewModel();
    }
```

oneViewModel.cs (viewmodel 1)

```
  async oneViewModel()
   {
      TestLabel = "View Mode 1"
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(Shell.Current.CurrentState);
   }
```

twoViewModel.cs (viewmodel 2)

```
async twoViewModel()
{
    TestLabel = "View Mode 2"
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(RandomPage);
}
```

Comment: this makes absolutely zero sense.  But if you want to change the VM a page is bound to, just reassign `BindingContext`

Comment: tried that already, didnt worked . if i reassign BindingContext to 2nd viewmodel than it doesnt reconsie TestLabel or any of the view objects. do you have an example that can example more? feel free to post an answer down

Answer (score -1):

just update the page's `BindingContext`

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,100,0,0">
    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
    <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

code-behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new VM("one");
    }

    void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindingContext = new VM("two");
    }
}

public class VM
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public VM(string desc)
    {
        this.Description = desc;
    }
}
```